# Phpmyadmin is not working in xampp

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I have recently installed xampp v3.2.2.start apache and and mysql when i try to access php my admin i got an error

```
MySQL said: Documentation
#2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
— The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Retry to connect
```

I did the following changes
update config.inc.php 
change

```
`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma' to $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'root';`
```

and

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1'
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost:8080';
```

delete `ib_logfile0` file and `ib_logfile` restart apache..but still the same error.please help me

Comment: Mysql isn't running on port 8080..

Comment: @Philipp thanks for your command so i have chenge the port?from httpd files

Comment: No, inside the config.inc.php, you have to use 3306

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL runs on port `3306` and not on port `8080`, so you have to change the port inside `config.inc.php`.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:8080' to   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3306'
```

Answer (score 2):

I had faced same issue because i had change file

> xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini

I solved by Below changes **//it should be 3306 default.**

> [client]
>
> ```
> # password       = your_password 
> port            = 3307 **//it should be 3306 default.**
> socket          = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
>
> # The MySQL server
> [mysqld] 
> port= 3307 **//it should be 3306 default.**
> socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
> ```
>
> Restart apache and mysql services in xampp

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

I have run MYSQL on port **3333**, it will change the port inside of **config.inc.php** file.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1' 

to   

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3333'
```

It works, Fine!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following steps worked for me:

1. Go to the data folder of MySQL(on windows using default installation you should find on this path C:\xampp\mysql\data)
2. Backup Log files and delete them: make backup copies of these two files  ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 (Note that they are created during the runtime for InnoDB  removing them will solve your most likely solve the problem, nonetheless I'd recommend you make copies of the aforementioned files somewhere else, in case deleting doesn't fix the problem.
   Now delete them from the original directory xampp\mysql\data
3. Restart MySQL and Apache,
   Hope it helps someone out there who got stuck on this problem  like myself.